# How to use is and are in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, irregular-plurals

Which of the following is correct:

1. The price to pay for these favors is souls
2. The price to pay for these favors are souls

Comment: The text doesn't make sense, so unsurprisingly there's no "correct" way of phrasing it. What you intend it to mean is *The **currency** used to pay the price for these favours is "souls"*, but your version is structurally equivalent to, say, *The price of a packet of cigarettes is dollars* - which is obviously nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say “the price are” is to ignore the grammatical connection of subject and following verb. Singular subject requires singular verb; plural subject requires plural verb.

Let us examine the other version:

By using the word “is”, the sentence sets up an equivalence between the subject and the object. By putting price as the subject it defines the nature of the equivalent object. In this case price is a singular noun, defining its equivalent object as singular.

So how are we to understand “souls” as a singular noun? There are at least two possibilities. “souls” may be seen as a singular group noun when it occurs in these circumstance. Or there may be an ellipsis: the price to pay is (a set of) souls.

Use the first version.